# The newest AVD emulator rejects my budget webcam (wasn't an issue before)

Tags: android, android-studio, webcam, android-virtual-device

I've just installed the latest Android Studio (v3.1.2) with all required things to run some emulated Android firmware and test an application in it. I tried to attach my webcam to an emulated phone to simulate its own inbuilt camera, following guides you can find around (and on this site as well), doing everything as it should be done - yet none of all apps I tested were able to use it. They were just spitting some "Camera encountered an issue" kind of errors.

Here is a relevant command's output:

`K:\Android\SDK\emulator\emulator -webcam-list -avd
emulator: WARNING: enumerateDevices: Webcam device '\\\usb#vid_0ac8&pid_3500&mi_00#6&197c435a&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global' does not support required dimensions.`

So, apparently current version of AVD deems my webcam as "unworthy". I have a budget A4-Tech PK-910H device alright, yet it's capable of 2MP video stream, does even better when it comes to photos. How it can be possibly not enough? Why does it even care, and why it didnt' before?

I used a very similar setup a year ago, and everything worked like a charm. Even more, **I used MUCH worse webcam back then without any issues** (this old camera is still with me, and it isn't accepted by AVD the same way; that's why I actually bought the new one, assuming 2MP just must be enough for everything). Nothing was changed since that day, except of Studio's and AVD's versions, so I'm pretty sure those are culprits.

Is it possible to resolve it without reinstalling everything from some old obsolete Studio's package? May be I can somehow use an older AVD emulator in parallel to the newest one?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I need by installing Android Studio 2.3 with an older version of AVD emulator (25.3). I got the package from [this site](https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/old).

Ironically, my new webcam still didn't work with it, though in a different manner. It at least was shown as connected, and in the app I need to test, instead of spitting an error, there was just black screen when the app tried to get feed from it. I suppose this may be due to the fact all webcams are connected using some BGR4 pixel format. May be it's not supported by this model.

The old camera still worked like a charm, so I'm good for now. A rotten egg flies in direction of Google, for meddling with a perfectly working feature for no reason, breaking it as a result.

Comment: Same problem here with a Dell XPS 9550 up-the-nose ;-) camera and a lowly GEMBIRD one, but not so much luck to get anything going as I can´t downgrade, because I wanted to try out ARcore. Guess they screwed sth up as they rushed out AR toolkit.